# C++ Multiple connections with sockets multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I'm working with sockets, and learning about them.

Now I'm stuck. I want to handle multiple connections, so I though doing that with multi-threading (I know is low scalable, and is better a thread pool or asynchronous sockets), but I can't manage to handle more than one connection each time.

When I connect to the socket I can't connect with other client until the first socket have been closed.

Here is my code, and sorry for my bad english.

```
void IRCServer::StartIRC(char * IP, int PORT) {

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&wsa);

    listenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    PVOID buff;

    saServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saServer.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    saServer.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_pton(AF_INET, IP, &buff);

    if (bind(listenSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&saServer, sizeof(saServer)) != 0) {
        printf("Error al bindear el socket\n");
        delete(this);
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (listen(listenSocket, SOMAXCONN))
        wprintf(L"failed to listen socket..");
    else
        wprintf(L"Listening on socket..\n on port %d", PORT);

    while (1) {
        SOCKET clientSocket = SOCKET_ERROR;

        clientSocket = (accept(listenSocket, NULL, NULL));

        if (clientSocket != SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("Client connected\n");
            DWORD threadID;
            HANDLE myHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &run, (LPVOID)clientSocket, 0, &threadID);          
        }
    }
};
```

And here is my thread function

```
static DWORD WINAPI run(LPVOID clientSocket) {
    printf("Thread %d",GetCurrentThreadId());
    char buffer[MAXBUFF];

    recv((SOCKET)clientSocket, buffer, MAXBUFF, 0);
    //Testing if recv something
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXBUFF; i++)
        printf("%c", buffer[i]);

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: You need to check how many bytes you get from `recv()` and keep reading till you get all the bytes you are expecting.

Comment: @MarkSetchell i dont worry about that, im worrying about that if i run two clients only 1 gets connected

Comment: Can you add some print-debugging? Before and after you call "accept" for starters. Or use a debugger :-)

Comment: The server code has problems (like never closing connections), but it looks like it handles multiple clients.  The problem you are asking about is probably in the client code

Comment: @cnicutar im stupid -.-', i was trying to connect through my explorer, but if i connect through my client.exe i can connect multiple, but idk why i can connect with browser

Comment: @MattTimmermans yep yep, i know, but i didnt do it because i was looking if all is working good